# android tts speaking loss control under screen rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, text-to-speech

I have a TTS object. This TTS object repeats the word 'help'. I have a boolean flag. When this flag is set to false, the while loop is broken, and TTS object stop. Below is the code. Basically, tts is initiated in OnCreate, and destroyed in OnDestroy. There is a button to start tts and a button to stop tts.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    IniTts();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if (_tts != null)
    {
        _tts.shutdown();

    }
    super.onDestroy();


}   
public OnBottonPressedStartShutting() {
        _tts.speak("help", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm); 
}

public OnBottonPressedStopShutting() {
        bContinueTtsPlay  = false; 
}


public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        if (bContinueTtsPlay == true) _tts.speak("help", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm); ;
}
```

it works as expected but it fails in below two cases:
 1. i rotate screen
 2. press home button and reopen the suspended app.
In both case, I find i can still hear 'help voice' repeatedly, but i could not stop it by press the 'stop button'.

I suppose when screen rotate, the tts object is shut down, and after screen rotate, tts object is reinstated. The request from 'runOnUiThread' continue and hence i can still hear the 'help voice'. But it turns out i cannot stop it by pressing 'stop button'.
Please have a look at above code and tell me where is the wrong logic.
thanks!

Comment: try this android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" for your activity.

Comment: thanks, but this wont help me to solve case 2. Besides, I really want to know why above code does not work, thanks.